# How can I render .obj model in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, urhosharp, urho3d

I have a .obj file that has a 3D body in it and I want to render it in a Xamarin.Forms app that already exists(made with MvvmCross), so I just want to create a new ContentPage that has the rendered body. The user should be able to view the body from different perspectives and maybe click on it to highlight some parts, but that's it.

I found out about UrhoSharp and I also know that I can use Metal and Vulkan bindings for Xamarin, but as I'm a beginner in 3D apps I don't know which one would be best for my scenario, that's why I would like someone to point me in the right direction for this scenario. For UrhoSharp I found [this loader](https://github.com/patrickabadi/UrhoCustomObj) which only works on Windows 10, the Android app doesn't load anything and the iOS app renders the body but I can't move the camera around it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin forms is good for making apps that are like "Forms" in which you fill out some information and submit.

The best way to do more 3D work is using Xamarin Native, Unity or if you want it to be a small part of your Xamarin Forms app, you can simply create a Custom 3D [Renderer in Xamarin Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).

The beauty of Xamarin is that you can access all the native APIs, so you would just follow tutorials on using the native APIs to access those OBJ files. For iOS, you would just be looking for a tutorial on how to use ARKit and then make small tweaks to add the obj file [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45143887/how-to-place-a-3d-model-of-type-obj-with-arkit).
Do the same thing for android!